# OpenLayers and the legend

Tags: web-mapping, openlayers-2, api

Is it a possibility in OL to add a legend (symbology) directly to (under) particular layer (not only switch on/off the layer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is not available in OpenLayers trunk. Other toolkits -- such as GeoExt -- or other extended functionality -- as demonstrated in the previously-linked sandbox -- may provide this functionality, but none are available in the stock/base OpenLayers install.

Answer (score 3):

Assume in the Legend [Table of Contents/Layers] you still want to show map layers with on/off switch but with the symbology of each under each one.

Such as:

http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/jvanulden/openlayers/examples/extended-layerswitcher.html

View Source reveals that
it is using Web Map Context (WMC)

http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wmc

```
var format = new OpenLayers.Format.WMC({'layerOptions': 
layerOptions});

var xmlParser = new OpenLayers.Format.XML()
```

(XML is 'hidWMC' at bottom of source code)

```
Legend
 // add the LayerSwitcher (a.k.a. Map Legend)
                layerSwitcher = new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher();
                layerSwitcher.ascending = false;
                layerSwitcher.useLegendGraphics = true;

                map.addControl(layerSwitcher);
```

Try recreating the example then change for your requirements (content)

Comment: Yes it was exactly my idea. How can i do it?

Comment: updated answer - with code from the example source